# SELECT CASE SQL ORACLE ODDS

Tags: sql, oracle, case-when

I have a simple table with a column and i would like to use a select case with two cases one for even row and another for odd row.

```
SELECT  CASE  WHEN new_table_row_is_even THEN DO_EVEN..ELSE DO_ODD
                  END
FROM new_table
```

for instance

```
table
-------
1300
2400
4000
8000
..
```

Is it possible to put like new_table_row_is_even %2 so when the row number is even the first DO_EVEN execute if not it will be DO_ODD.

Thank you,

Mat

Comment: How do you define "odd row" and "even row"? A value in a particular column?

Comment: What are 'do_even' and 'do_odd' - functions. procedures. something else?

Comment: There are no particular column do_even and do_odd it's just something to do

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `row_number()` function to count the rows. Rows in a relational database are not sorted, so you need to apply some sort criteria in order to get a stable numbering of rows.

```
select some_column, 
       case 
         when mod(row_number() over (order by some_other_column), 2) = 0 then 'even'
         else 'odd'
       end
from the_table
```

In the above statement you need to replace the `order by some_other_column` with a proper column name that gives you the order you want so that assigning a row number makes sense.

Comment: Thank you four your answer, it almost works, i don't want to order by some_other_column, i need the proper order how can i do without order by. I need to keep the order of the row

Comment: @Mat There is no such thing as "*the order of the rows*". Rows in a relational database are ***NOT*** sorted. You _can_ leave out the `order by` but don't complain if you get different results each time you run the statement

Comment: One might use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY rowid )`, but the value of the `rowid` pseudocolumn might change if the row is deleted and re-added, and they are not guaranteed to be ordered in the same order as the rows were inserted in any case.